# Derivation of statistical test for equality of two regression slopes

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have some observations $(y_{1i}, x_{1i})$, $i = \{1,2...,n_1\}$ and $(y_{2j} , x_{2j})$, $j = \{1,2...,n_2\}$.
The covariates $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2j}$ are fixed, the $y_{1i}$ and $y_{2j}$ are values of independent, normally distributed r.v.’s $Y_{1i}$ and $Y_{2j}$.
Simple linear regressions are appropriate models:

$y_{1i} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_{1i} + \epsilon_{1i}$

$y_{2i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{2i} + \epsilon_{2i}$

Also we have $Var(\epsilon_{1i} )= Var(\epsilon_{2j})$.

I would like test for $H_0: \alpha_1 - \beta_1 = 0$.

I found for example [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/regression/hypothesis-testing-significance-regression-line-slope/comparing-slopes-two-independent-samples/) that:
$ \frac{\alpha_1-\beta_1}{\sqrt{s_{b1}^2+s_{b2}^2}} \sim t(n_1+n_2-4) $

I don't get why, since for a t-distribution we need something like

$T = \frac{V}{\sqrt{Z/m}}$ with $ Z\sim \chi^2_m$ and $V \sim \mathcal{N(0,1)}$.

But $\alpha_1-\beta_1\sim \mathcal{N(0,1)}$ is not given. Does the test make sense nonetheless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under $H_0$, $\alpha = \beta$ and given that $\epsilon_i$, $i=1,2$ follows a normal distribution you have
$$
\frac{ \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} }{\sigma_{\hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} }}\sim N (0,1),
$$
where $\sigma_{\hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} } = \sigma\sqrt{
 \frac{(n_2 - 2) S^2_{x_2} +  (n_1 - 2)S^2_{x_1}}{ S^2_{x_1} S^2_{x_2} } }.
$
Note that (abusing notation, but you will get the idea) $$
S_{x_1}^2 + S_{x_2}^2 = \sigma^2\left(
 \frac{\chi^2_{n_1-2}}{n_1-2}
+ 
\frac{\chi^2_{n_2-2}}{n_2-2}
\right).
$$
Recall that for independent r.v.s $\chi^2_{n_1-2} + \chi^2_{n_2-2} = \chi ^2 _{n_1 + n_2 - 4}.$ Try to work out the algebra to show that 
$$
\frac{ \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} }{\sigma_{\hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} }}
/\sqrt{\frac{ \chi^2_{n_1  + n_2 - 4} } { n_1 + n_2 - 4} }
\sim t_{n_1 + n_2  - 4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I, unfortunately, cannot follow your answer. First, shouldn't this be:
 $\sigma_{\hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} } = \sigma\sqrt{
 \frac{S^2_{x_2}(n_2-2) +  S^2_{x_1}(n_1-2)}{ S^2_{x_1} S^2_{x_2} } }
$. I also don' know why $ S_x_1^2 + S_x_2^2 = \sigma ... $ . Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. The main idea is that the denominator is indeed a Chi square r.v. divided by its dof and the nominator is indeed $N(0,1)$.  To show it explicitly, just plug the explicit form of the variances and premultipiy it by $\sigma/\sigma$ just to see the aforementioned ratio of random variables.